# Android studio building gradle project not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-sdk-2.3

I had installed `android studio 2.3.2` and gave offline SDK path `('D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\studio_latest\Android_SDK_(Do_not_touch)')`. After that, I tried to create a new ***HelloWorld*** project. When all processes complete, the studio gives `'building 'HelloWorld' gradle project info'` and stop there, nothing happens after that.

Could you please help me with suggestions?
For instance:

- is my gradle path right?
- is my sdk configuration wrong?

Comment: Have you connect to the internet?